# Как использовать macbook как монитор?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, monitor

У меня в наличии два мака один на 16 дюймов, другой на 13. Хочу использовать 13-дюймовый как сторонний экран для первого. В основном в сети представлены рекомендации и советы как подключить сторонний монитор к маку: через hdmi и usb-c, там все просто. На запрос 'How to use macbook as external monitor for another macbook' выдало статью [https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/second-screen-mac-3621421/#:~:text=Open%20System%20Preferences%20%3E%20Displays.,into%20the%20arrangement%20you%20require.](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/second-screen-mac-3621421/#:%7E:text=Open%20System%20Preferences%20%3E%20Displays.,into%20the%20arrangement%20you%20require.).
Я подсоединил маки друг к другу через usb-type-c, но они друг друга не видят - то есть, я в мониторах не вижу список подключенных устройств. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей и как Вы с ним справились?

Comment: Есть такая прога [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy). Она позволяет расшарить мышку, клавиатуру, буфер обмена и проч. между разными компьютерами/ОС. Так можно работать за разными компьютерами как за одним.

Comment: чёрт, у меня задачка точь-в-точь! к 16 макбуку про подключить 13й как монитор! удалось решить задачку? synergy пробовал?

Answer (score 1):

Так не получится сделать. MacBook невозможно использовать как внешний монитор – такая функция доступна только для iMac и называется Target Display Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Посредством Deskreen можно расшарить экран на любое устройство с браузером. Сам попробовал сделать айфон и айпад вторым дисплеем для мак - все получилось. https://deskreen.com/lang-ru

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)